# Ubuntun 22.04: when connected with NetworkManager OpenVPN, DNS doesn't use the VPN DNS server

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, openvpn, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu 22.04
I have an OpenVPN to my company via NetworkManager in gnome.

Most of the interal systems work, but for example portal.azure.com has 2 DNS records, a public and private zone one. And when I am on the VPN, it should use the private zone, otherwise I am blocked by the firewall and can't see anything.

I removed the /etc/resolve.conf symlink to fallback to the default behavior, and when I connect, I see the nameservers of the company added to the bottom

```
nameserver 89.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver 89.xxx.xxx.xxx

# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
search home company.xx 
nameserver 10.xx.xx.xx
nameserver 10.xx.xx.xx
```

This doesn't give me access to the private stuff in portal.azure.com

When I swap the nameservers, then it does work:

```
search home company.xx 
nameserver 10.xx.xx.xx
nameserver 10.xx.xx.xx

nameserver 89.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver 89.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

What can I do to make this work automatically, or via systemd-resolved.

If I open `/run/NetworkManager/no-stub-resolv.conf`  then I do see the correct file for /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search company.xx home
nameserver 10.xx.xx.xx
nameserver 10.xx.xx.xx
nameserver 89.xx.xx.xx
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 89.xx.xx.xx
```

I could replace the /etc/resolv.conf with the NetworkManager version, but it seems this should be done automatically. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For me worked just installing `resolvconf` on Ubuntu 22.04:

`apt install resolvconf`

Reboot (not sure if needed) and DNS is working using OpenVPN + Neworkmanager.

Comment: Thanks, I installed it but it still generated incorrect order of the nameservers. the VPN dns servers were at the bottom and it didn't see the vpn-local domain names

Comment: A reboot was not necessary for me. Just install then reconnect to the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04. On 16.04, everything worked perfectly.

The order of the DNS is [now fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/network-manager/+bug/1624317) i guess. On my new system (xubuntu 22.04) it seems, that OpenVPN makes some wierd things.

On the OpenVPN routing settings i setted up the last option:
[OpenVPN Routing Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAv6n.png)

After the connection is established, i can use an local search with nslookup. On the first attempt i everything gets allright. If i make a second request, i'll get the answer from the public DNS Server:

```
markus@Host:~$ nslookup localaddr
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   localaddr.fqdn.com
Address: 10.0.0.xxx
localaddr.fqdn  canonical name = xxx.public.net.

markus@Host:~$ nslookup localaddr
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
localaddr.fqdn  canonical name = xxx.public.net.
Name:   xxx.public.net
Address: 145.xx.xxx.xx
```

I guess it depends on a secure DNS option or the cache behavior that messes it up. After the TTL time is over or with `sudo resolvectl flush-caches`
, i'll get the same answer as shown above again.

If someone have an idea, please let me know.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1270174)

Comment: I still haven't solved the issue as well. What I do now after connecting/disconnecting the VPN using the UI (probably a different program in xubuntu), I copy /run/NetworkManager/no-stub-resolv.conf to /etc/resolv.conf and it works as expected. Nasty solution for now, but at least it works and I can continue.